# How to dynamically add rows to my table and postback the data to view

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

As the question suggests I am using ENTITY FRAMEWORK in my ASP.NET application in which I have a table which the user can add rows to and input data into it. I need to know how I can post this data back to controller.

My models : (There were generated by EF when i used database first approach)

```
public partial class TRA_FORMS
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public TRA_FORMS()
        {
            this.TRA_ITEMS = new HashSet<TRA_ITEMS>();

        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name of TRA")]
        public string NAME_OF_TRA { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Requested amount")]
        public Nullable<double> AMOUNT_REQUESTED { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Name of commitee member making application")]
        public string COMMITEE_MEMBER_NAME { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Date of last AGM")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DATE_OF_AGM { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Signed")]
        public string SIGNED { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Dated")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DATED { get; set; }



        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<TRA_ITEMS> TRA_ITEMS { get; set; }
    }


public partial class TRA_ITEMS
    {

        public int ITEM_ID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Description of Items")]
        public string DESC_OF_ITEMS { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
        public Nullable<int> QUANTITY { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Cost")]
        public Nullable<double> COST { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "From ID")]
        public Nullable<int> FORM_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual TRA_FORMS TRA_FORMS { get; set; }
    }
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]

        public ActionResult Index(TRA_FORMS traForms)
        {

            return View();
        }
```

I'm not showing my view here as It's wrong and I dont know how to go about it. But the view accepts a model of type TRA_FORMS. I have a table in this view (regular html ) which has 3 columns - each for properties from the TRA_ITEMS model. The Desc of items, quantity and cost. Users can add any number of items to this table. Ideally on postback it should postback a List which holds each item added by the user but i don't know how to do this. I've looked at several Stack overflow questions related to this and been looking for solutions the whole day but I'm a newbie to ASP.NET so having trouble applying most answers i found to my scenario.

Comment: I would search for master detail examples like [this](http://www.dotnetawesome.com/2015/09/how-to-create-master-detail-entry-form-in-aspnet-mvc4.html). Generally, your Index view is a list of your master items (TRA_FORMS) where you might provide ADD, EDIT and DELETE functions. When the user selects an item to edit, route them to an Edit GET action where you build the model and go to the view. From there you POST to the Edit POST action, save the data, handle errors, etc.

Comment: @SteveGreene when routing them to a Edot GET action how can i Pass the model that my view is using to this get action?

Comment: Use an ActionLink on your Index page that passes the key(ID) to the Edit Action GET. In there, fetch your existing entity and send it to the view. Good example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view).